# dynamically sizing an expandableListView inside of a LinearLayout

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a expandableListView inside of linearLayout with other widgets and content surrounding it.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to change the layoutHeight to be able to match the size of the expandableListView its visible content changes and parents are expanded and contracted.

wrap_content doesn't seem to work in the layout file. Is there a way to do it at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

A relative layout may respond better.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll try a test layout using a relative layout. I would like to understand what the reasoning for your instinct is.